# Batch program | Loop breaks, and output display

Tags: loops, batch-file, if-statement, display

I'm currently trying to write a batch program that takes in two numbers that the user inputs. I had to create an exit number for the user if they choose to exit the program by entering the number 22. If the user doesn't exit the program it goes to check that the second number entered isn't 0. If it is 0 the user has to reenter another number and then proceed to divide the first number by the second number and display it.

My current issue is that if the user enters a correct value for both variables it still requests the user to another number for the secondNum. The program is supposed to continue running until the user enters the exit number 22. As for the display I don't want to only display the out put but rather this: 10 divided by 2 = 5.

```
@echo off
title lodiDpgm4

echo resulst.txt
echo Daniel Lodi >> results.txt
set datet=%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-4,4% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
echo %datet% >> results.txt

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:main
cls

set /p firstNum="Enter your first number"
if !firstNum! == 22 goto :eof
set /p secondNum="Enter your second number"
if !secondNum! == 22 goto :eof
if "%secondNum%"=="0" goto :loop

goto :calculate

:loop
set /p "secondNum=You can not divide by 0 please enter another number"
if "%secondNum%"=="0" goto :loop
pause

:calculate
@echo off
set /a results=(firstNum/secondNum)
echo %results%
pause

goto :main

:eof
cls
@echo off
echo.
echo.
echo. Promgram has ended, thank you.
```

Comment: Try to think like the processor. What happens after `if "%secondNum%"=="0" goto :loop` and `pause`? - Right. The next lines to process are `:loop` and `set /p ...` That's exactly, what it does. You are missing `goto :calculate` here.

Comment: So after the prompt put goto :calculate, but wouldn't that assume the user inputted something aside from 0 and go to calculate?

Comment: put it between `pause` and `:loop` (btw: if this is your whole code, there is no need for delayed expansion)

Comment: I've edited the program with the goto :calculate and added a goto: main so it continues to run a loop, I got the idea from you thank you. As for the output is it possible to use a for loop like this: `for /L %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (
    SET /a VAR=%%x %% 5
    set /a CAL=!VAR! %% 5
    echo %%x MOD 5 = !CAL!
)` @Stephan

Comment: yes, of course that's possible. But why do you `modulo` twice? Do you still have a problem with your code above or is your initial issue solved?

Comment: @Stephan I'm sorry that's just an example not what I intend to use and yea i have the second issue which is the second paragraph I wrote if you missed that? I want to be able to show the calculations being done such as 4 divided by 2 = 2 similar to how the above loop displays 1 mod 5 = 1. However the for loop example is using a variable that is being incremented by the for loop and a value of 5 while in my program I have two inputs being taken in from the user.

Comment: like `echo %firstNum% divided by %secondNum% = %results%`?